# Are those Lists safe thread in Parallel.For?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety, parallel.foreach

I must remove *lock* object from `Parallel.ForEach`. Should I use `ConcurrentBag` or just remove it? Is it thread safe without the *lock* object?

`results` is a `List<>`.

```
Parallel.ForEach(entityList, options,
() =>
{
    List<Customer> childrenResult = new List<Customer>();
    return childrenResult;
},
(childrenObject, loopState, childrenResult) =>
{
    childrenResult.AddRange(currentChildrenManager.Prepare(childrenObject, currentAnalyticalDataHolder, () => loopState.IsStopped, out childrenAllData));
    return childrenResult;
},
(childrenResult) =>
{
    lock (lockingObject)
    {
        if (childrenResult == null)
            results.AddRange(new List<Customer>());
        else if (currentChildrenManager.RowOrFilteredRowLimitation == null)
            results.AddRange(childrenResult);
        else
        {
            int leftCount = currentChildrenManager.RowOrFilteredRowLimitation.GetRelativRowLimitation(provider.IsForGenerationTime) - results.Count();
            if (leftCount > 0)
            {
                if (childrenResult.Count() > leftCount)
                {
                    tAllData = currentChildrenManager.OnlyFirst;
                    results.AddRange(childrenResult.Take(leftCount));
                }
                else
                    results.AddRange(childrenResult);
            }
            else
            {
                tAllData = currentChildrenManager.OnlyFirst;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the code you presented uses the overload which takes in a `localInit` value and uses a `localFinally` `Func<T>` and `Action<T>` respectively that looks like this:

```
public static ParallelLoopResult ForEach<TSource, TLocal>(
    IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    ParallelOptions parallelOptions,
    Func<TLocal> localInit,
    Func<TSource, ParallelLoopState, TLocal, TLocal> body,
    Action<TLocal> localFinally
)
```

The lock **is still mandatory** because the final operation has to add items to the underlying list in parallel. You *could* use a `ConcurrentBag<T>` for the final concatenation, but I'd suggest you benchmark both ways to see which gives you the more performant result.

Perhaps a different approach which may suit you better is to use [*PLINQ*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688(v=vs.110).aspx). This way, you can operate on multiple items in parallel and only at the end use a `ToList` to create a `List<T>` containing your result:

```
var result = entityList.AsParallel()
                       .Select(childObject => 
                                currentChildrenManager.Prepare(
                        childObject, currentAnalyticalDataHolder, out childrenAllData))
                       .ToList();
// Modify the list further if needed.
```